# Sun Virtualbox: Cannot Install Windows 95 or 98

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-98

I'm running XP and I've tried to install Windows 95 and 98 with the official CDs in Virtualbox. Both of them give the error:

> FATAL: no bootable medium found! System Halted

I've mounted the CD drives within Virtualbox and also tried to change the boot order so that the CD drive is first but to no avail. I don't understand exactly what's going on here.

Answer (score 11):

Windows 95 or 98 are not bootable cd's. Only from Windows 98 SE Bootable options were available. Try to get hold of Boot disk images for Windows 95/98 (note:- download file which has the .img extension). Use it to load in VirtualBox floppy.

Comment: Note that even if you get this working, Windows 95 and 98 are not well supported in Virtualbox.  They will run, but very slowly.  Since your host if Windows XP, you're much better off using Microsoft Virtual PC as your hypervisor.

Answer (score 3):

Try them with Virtual PC. It often works better for Microsoft operating systems.

If the CD doesn't work with VPC, you can be sure it's corrupted.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with either of the CDs. The 98 CD is a bit scratched but the 95 CD was in a case and is in almost perfect condition. It's almost as if the visualization programs arn't letting the virtual "OS" detect the CD drive

Comment: The CD might not be bootable. Does its root directory contain any .exe or .inf files?

Comment: They sure do. And they boot up when I restart my computer, just not in Virtualization.

Comment: I would tend to say that this is impossible, but perhaps miracles never cease.

Answer (score 1):

for windows 95, you need to use a boot disk (windows 98 boot disk works) to fdisk and format the VM hard drive, and to "start with CD ROM support" to read the wind95/98 install disk.

download a cd iso version of a windows 98 bootdisk.
burn the 98 boot disk iso image on a cd
boot with the 98 boot disk CD and "with CD Rom support"
this should boot the VM into dos mode.
(note: look at what drive the CD rom is actually assigned, as the boot disk takes A:, and Diagnostics took D: my CD drive was E:)
run fdisk
create primary partition, etc.
restart, with the 98 boot disk cd again
run format
restart again
change the CD in the drive to the windows install Disk
change to the CD ROM Drive (E: for me) "cd e:"
check CD contents "dir /w" and llok for setup.exe
run setup.exe
laugh a gleefull laugh as windows installs
frown a sadsack frown as windows 95 client cant share files with its host

Answer (score 0):

[FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) works also. Of course, you can boot on it as a virtual drive from the iso.